# Issues with building Kivy APK with buildozer

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I wrote a simple Kivy app on Mac OsX that replicates buttons:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout






class ButtonApp(App):

    def add_button(self, none):
        button = Button(text='Press Me too!')
        button.bind(on_press=self.add_button)
        self.b.add_widget(button)


    def build(self):
        self.b = BoxLayout()
        button = Button(text="Press me!")
        button.bind(on_press=self.add_button)
        self.b.add_widget(button)
        return self.b


if __name__ == "__main__":

    ButtonApp().run()
```

However, when I initiate the buildozer file with buildozer init, and run it with buildozer android debug I get the following error

```
  self.target.build_package()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 517, in build_package
    version = self.buildozer.get_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 675, in get_version
    ' (looking for `{1}`)'.format(fn, regex))
Exception: Unable to find capture version in ./main.py
 (looking for `__version__ = ['"](.*)['"]`)
```

I've tried many solutions including switching the locations of the file, changing the version, adding `__version__ = "1.2.0"` to main.py file, and all with no success. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Buildozer works only on linux for the android package, this error is because you were on OSX